# Synchronization in multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, runnable

I am a beginner in multi threading and came across this concept :

> 2 methods m1 being non static synchronised and m2 being static
>   synchronised and 2 threads T1 accessing m1 with object o1 and T2
>   accessing m2 can run concurrently since m1 and m2 are synchronised on 2
>   different objects.

Then why in the below case Threads are not able to access the method concurrently even though the objects are different as Foo.class and f1 and f2?

```
class Foo implements Runnable{
    void run()
        synchronised(Foo.class)
        { 
         ....

        }
    }
}
class Test{
    psvm(){

        Foo f1 = new Foo();
        Foo f2 = new Foo();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(f1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(f2);
        t1.start();
        t2.start(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you synchronize on a common object, `Foo.class`.

Comment: Note: the threads are able to invoke `run()` concurrently; they just can't execute the synchronized block concurrently.

Comment: But according to the quoted statement aren't they supposed to not block each other since they are on 2 different object, Foo.class and f1, f2?

Comment: `Foo.class` is one object. You're synchronizing on that one object in both threads.

Comment: You're not synchronizing on `f1` or `f2`.

Comment: The quoted statement is also pretty unclear in my opinion.  It says "accessing m1 with object o1" but never says o1 is used to synchronize anything.

Comment: What would be the objects of synchronisation if i had synchronised (this) instead of the above? Would it be f1 or f2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 2 methods m1 being non static synchronised and m2 being static
>   synchronised and 2 threads T1 accessing m1 with object o1 and T2
>   accessing m2 can run concurrently since m1 and m2 are synchronised on
>   2 different objects.

non-static method m1 is synchronized on `this`(current instance), static method m2 is synchronized on `this.getClass()`(the class object current instance belongs to). They are synchronized on **different objects**, so they can not block each other.

In the posted code, the synchronized block has an explicit monitor lock `Foo.class`, different `Foo` instances share the same `Foo.class`, that means the code is  synchronized on the **same object**. So, only one thread can enter the synchronized block, they others will get blocked until it exists.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the synchronisation has been done as a **class level locking**   .

When one thread is accessing that the other thread waits for its turn ..

Synchronisation is used when you want to limit concurrency such that all threads can have their turn for accessing the resource